Impulse Response And convolution
What is a impulse Response Function ? Can it be called as a Resolution function? And in my math text book the resolution function is defined as the probability density function which gives the probability that a instrument records an output y=0,when integrated between y and y+dy. Now when the resolution function is convolved with true function to be measured f(x),produces a observed distribution h(z) now my question is what does the probability that an output y =0 recorded by the apparatus has to do with the resolution function? Or impulse response function? And why the resolution function has to be as close as possible to delta function.

This seem to be math, not physics?

@trula Actually it is a good question and it is not about "math". Whether it is "physics" or "signal processing" or "engineering" is debatable, but it is at the heart of measuring in noise with real instruments. When I have a little more time I will write an answer.

This video from 3blue1brown might help - But what is a convolution?

Assume a linear system by which I mean from the emission of the "signal", whatever that may mean in a given physical situation, to the instant of detection it is passing through a set of linear transformations including both the signal itself and any interference it may encounter.
The whole sequence of transformations being linear can be described by its impulse response. This means that if the signal is an impulse $\delta (t)$ and its response is $h(t)$ then if the signal is $x(t),$ then the response is the convolution $$y(t)=h(t) \otimes x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt' h(t')x(t-t')=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt' h(t-t')x(t') \tag{1}$$
Ideally any instrument that is used to detect/measure the "signal" $x(t)$ will not change the output $y(t)$ so if $x(t)=\delta(t)$ then $y(t)=\delta(t).$ This would assure that if the input is $x(t)=a_1\delta(t-t_1)+a_2\delta(t-t_2)$ then also $y(t)=x(t)=a_1\delta(t-t_1)+a_2\delta(t-t_2),$ and we would get a perfect (noiseless) detection and resolution of the two impulses if $h(t)=1$.
Unfortunately, that cannot be had because, as a minimum,

an impulse is not a physically achievable signal because all signals have finite energy, and
all instruments have at their input a wideband "blackbody" noise of         essentially infinite strength that must be restricted to positive probability to allow detection.
All real instruments have restricted bandwidth, there is no $h(t)=1.$ Accordingly all instruments have, for practical and theoretical reasons, a finite bandwidth, e.g., a galvanometer cannot react instantaneously for it has inertia, etc.

As a signal detector, the job of the signal processor is to maximize the detection probability of the signal $x(t)$ in noise given the instrument. This detection maximization assumes that the signal is by itself in noise. The statistical alternative at any instant over which the processor is to decide is whether there is or is no signal when the signal is by itself. This is the basic and simplest detection problem and its solution in additive normal noise has been known since the 1930's (North, Wiener, Kolmogorov, Shannon, Bode, Woodward, Kotelnikov,....).
If the received noisy signal is $x(t)+\mathbf z(t)$ where $x(t)$ is a given finite energy signal and $\mathbf z(t)$ is a white normal noise then  the linear system whose output provides that at instant $T_0$ the highest signal to noise and ratio at the same time the highest probability of detection at a fixed false alarm rate is the impulse response $h(t)=x(T_0-t).$
If the instrument has a natural impulse response, say $m(t)$, then to design a good detection algorithm represented by the function $r(t)$ the ideal "filter" should combine the impulse responses so that $m(t)\otimes r(t)=h(t)=x(T_0-t).$ The most surprising result of all this is that maximum achievable signal to noise ratio (SNR, $\gamma$) is independent of the shape of the signal $x(t)$, it only depends on its energy $\mathcal E_p=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt x^2(t)$, specifically $\gamma = \frac{2\mathcal E_p}{\mathcal N_0}$, where $\mathcal N_0$ is the noise spectral density.
But that is good only for a single signal in noise and real life is more complicated. In reality the same signal is received many times, say multiple reflections and some such, and one reception may overlap and interfere with another. Also you may have to discriminate one given signal $x_1(t)$ from another quite different shaped, say, $x_2(t)$. Of course, if these were ideal impulses and there we no noise then discrimination would be simple in the "fairyland" noiseless case but we do not have that. Even if we could detect one powerful signal in noise, say $x_1$ by properly filtering with $h_1(t)=x_1(T_0-t)$ when it comes out from the detector as $y_1(t) =h_1(t)\otimes x_1(t)$  it will "ring" after the instant of detection $T_0$ and if there is another signal $x_2(t)$ to be detected that has started before $T_0$ the two will interfere even without noise.
A visible example of that type of interference is any basic astronomical instrument whose circular aperture acts as a 2D spatial filter whose impulse response is the Airy diffraction pattern. When a strong star is viewed then small stars may be buried in the diffraction sidelobes of the strong one. This is the resolution problem.
Actually, the solution of the resolution problem, pun intended, is not that the overall signal processing filter $h(t)$ be as close to an impulse as possible but that the output $y(t)$ of the signal processing chain be as close to possible to an impulse. You start with a very wide frequency band signal, it could be an impulse or chirped frequency signal, the important point is that it contain a very large set of frequencies. Then pass it through the instrument including its signal processor so that at its output all its various frequency terms are aligned in phase and amplitude to create a signal that is as close to an impulse as possible meanwhile maximizing the SNR. This is spread spectrum processing whose filter solution was found by Woodward, Klauder, Darlington, etc.

Sir as you were saying the Output y(t) =x(t) when x(t)=delta(t). Okay let's say we are not measuring signals and we are measuring some other physical quantity using a apparatus and it produces a response g(y) and y is the output. Now sir if the response is equal to delta function now what does it mean to say the probability that an output y=0 is measured between y and y+dy is given by g(y)dy( density function)? Does it mean the probability that instrument records zero is 100% if we integrate the resolution function? Even when the true function is not zero in that point?

A "signal" is just any physical quantity in a measuring instrument that you have to interpret. I am not sure if this what you are asking about but in a "delta" function $A\delta (t-\tau)$ there are two possible random quantities. These are the amplitude $A$ and the instant of occurrence $\tau$, both are significant and measurable and can be assigned a pdf. If $t$ is time then $\tau$ is the instant of measuring. If $t$ is length then $\tau$ is the location.

As the name may suggest, the impulse response function $h(t)$ of a system is its response (in time domain) to an impulsive force that can be modeled as a Dirac's delta for continuous-time systems, or an equivalent discrete function (ideally different from zero only at the first time-step) for discrete-time systems.
For a discrete-time system, you usually want a small time-step in order to better approximate an impulsive function.
Focusing only on continuous-time linear time invariant systems here, it's easy to prove the relation between that the transfer function $H(s)$ is the Laplace transform of the impulsive response function.
For a discrete-time system it's possible to repeat the proof using $Z$-transform instead of Laplace transform.
Proof.
A linear time invariant system can be written in time domain as
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = A x + B u \\
y = C x + D u \\
x(0) = x_0
\end{cases}$$
or in Laplace domain as
$$\begin{cases}
s \hat{x} = A \hat{x} + B \hat{u} + x_0 \\
\hat{y} = C \hat{x} + D \hat{u} \ , \\
\end{cases}$$
being $\hat{f}(s) = \mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \displaystyle \int_{t=0^-}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt$ the Laplace equation, $x(t)$ the state, $u(t)$ the input and $y(t)$ the output of the system.
It's possible to prove that the general response of the system in time or Laplace domains reads
$$y(t) = C e^{-A t} x_0 + \int_{\tau=0^-}^{t} h(t- \tau) u(\tau) d \tau$$
$$\hat{y}(s) = C \left( s I - A \right)^{-1} x_0 + H(s) \hat{u}(s) \ ,$$
being $h(t)$ the impulsive response function and $H(s)$ the transfer function,
$$h(t) = C e^{-At}B + D \delta(t)$$
$$H(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D \ .$$
Remarks.

The integral $$\int_{\tau=0^-}^{t} h(t- \tau) u(\tau) d \tau$$ is the convolution of the causal functions $h(t)$, $u(t)$;
A causal function can be defined as a function that it's identically zero before any action on the system, i.e. the system is considered at rest before $t=0$
Laplace transform of convolution of two functions equals the product of the Laplace transform of the two functions, i.e.
$$\mathscr{L}\left\{ \int_{\tau=0^-}^{t} h(t-\tau) u(\tau) d\tau \right\} = \mathscr{h(t)}(s) \, \mathscr{u(t)}(s) = H(s) \, \hat{u}(s)$$.

Now, let's find out why $h(t)$ is called the impulsive response function, considering a proper system ($D=0$) with zero initial conditions, $x_0 = 0$. Forcing the system with an impulsive force $u(t) = \delta(t)$, whose Laplace transform is $\hat{u}(s) = 1$, the response of the system is
$$y^{imp,0}(t) = h(t)$$
$$\hat{y}^{imp,0}(s) = H(s) \ ,$$
i.e. coincides with the impulsive response function $h(t)$ in time domain and its Laplace transform, the transfer function $H(s)$, in Laplace domain.
